# xpages : multiple partial refresh not working

Tags: xpages

Please help. When i run a single XSP.partialRefreshGet in xPages and it is working. But,it is not working while get multiple partial refresh. Anything is wrong on it? Kindly assist and thanks.

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[
        setInterval(function() {


XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:refreshPanel}", {
 onComplete: function() {
     XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:refreshPanel2}", {});
    }


} })
            }, 1000)
        ]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Comment: The Problem is the interval. Remove it, or  increase the time.

Comment: Hi, the reason to use setInterval method is require continue calling the function to refresh in order to always update the latest information. Hence, i can't remove this method. I have tried to increase the time and it is not working.

Answer (score 11):

When doing a partial refresh, a lock is set in the XSP object which stops all partialRefreshes until the current running refresh is completed or specific time is up (20 s by default).

To change this behaviour you can do two things:

1. change the intervall
2. allow a resubmition

But in both cases, this is **NOT** a good choice for your problem with the intervaled refresh, because this would just flood the server with useless requests while the server is still processing a already sent request.

Instead, you should recall your refreshes when your refreshes are completed (or failed). Something like this:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
   <xp:this.value>
      <![CDATA[
        function doIt(){
           XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:refreshPanel}", {
              onError: "restart()",
              onComplete: function() {
                 XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:refreshPanel2}", {
                    onComplete: "restart()",
                    onError: "restart()"
                 });
              }
           });
        }

        function restart(){
           window.setTimeout( "doIt()", 1000 );
        }

        doIt();
    ]]>
</xp:this.value>
```

P.S.
I typed this from my brain w/o checking the code on a computer.

Comment: Sven: You are only missing the () on the calls to the restart() function

Comment: @Newbs: You have created a fork bomb ;-) Added some quotes to stop it.

Comment: sorry. I have tried the code as above and it is unable to automatically refresh on the field of the panels. Anything is wrong? :)

Comment: Maybe the code is loaded before the XSP object exist. Try to surround the *doIt* call with a *XSP.addOnLoad( function(){ doIt() } );*

Answer (score 1):

XPages enforce, from client side, a 20s delay between partial refresh. The reason can be found in the `XSPClientDojo.js`, `canSubmit()` function comments:

> This should be called before any page submission, to prevent page re-submission, either accidentally when a user double-clicks on a link, or if the user is impatient compared to the expected time for a page refresh.
>   If the page has recently been submitted, it returns false, and the submission should be abandoned.

To bypass this behavour, you can just call `XSP.allowSubmit()` between the two `partialRefreshGet()`. Some this like that:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
<xp:this.value>
  <![CDATA[
    setInterval(function() {
      XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:refreshPanel}");
      XSP.allowSubmit();
      XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:refreshPanel2}");
    }, 1000)
  ]]>
</xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Comment: What happens if the server needs 1001 ms or more for a partial refresh?

Comment: I guess that the request will be queued on the server until the request queue become full, after that, the server will start rejecting connections. But the issue will be the same if I do only one refresh in the interval. I thing that using websockets for this sort of thing will work a lot better, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: When running multiple partial refreshes without "waiting" for their end, the browser can run into JavaScript errors, which may break the XPages application.